# how can i append a file into another file with a suitable format using script shell

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have this json file template.json

```
{
    "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
    "PTF_CONTENT": [
      {
        "NAME": "api_batch_API",
        "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
        "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And this file historique.json,It created by script bash , I call the script in Jenkinsfile

```
  [
   {
        "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
        "PTF_CONTENT": [
          {
            "NAME": "api_batch_API",
            "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
            "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
          }
        ]
     }
   ]
```

So when I do a build in jenkins an element has added in the last of file historique.json like below:

```
[
    {
           "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
           "PTF_CONTENT": [
             {
                "NAME": "api_batch_API",
                "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
                "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
              }
            ]
         }
]
{
        "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
        "PTF_CONTENT": [
          {
            "NAME": "api_batch_API",
            "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
            "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
          }
        ]
  }
```

And ect. So my question is how can I formatted the historique file to be like below:

```
 [
      {
           "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
           "PTF_CONTENT": [
                  {
                    "NAME": "api_batch_API",
                    "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
                    "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
                  }
        ]
     },

    {
            "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
            "PTF_CONTENT": [
              {
                "NAME": "api_batch_API",
                "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
                "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
              }
       ]
    }
]
```

This my script script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(cat template.json)

if [ -e $WORKSPACE/project/historique.json ];
then
  cat template.json >> historique.json
else
  cat <<-EOF > historique.json
   [
    $a
   ]
EOF
fi
```

PS: The file template.json change at each build in jenkins

The problem is the command after "then".
Any suggestion please??(And sorry for my English)

Comment: Have you tried [tag:jq]?

Comment: yes but i prefered not to use it ....

Comment: @oguz But if you have a proposition with it, tell me.

Comment: Well, `jq '. + [input]'` does what you want.

Comment: @oguz [input] it's the file or what ?

Comment: sorry , but if there is any solution like that: before append the element i delete the last character `]` then add `,` `element` `]` and like that solved, have you a suggestion @oguz ??

Comment: He forgot the filenames. `jq '. + [input]' historique.json template.json` The `.` becomes the array in the first file, and `input` is the object in the second file. It's then put in an array and appended to the first one.

Comment: @Shawn thanks , but how can i save the output in the same file historique.json?

Comment: The usual way. Redirect output to a temporary file, and then rename it.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After oguz ismail and shawn response the script file become like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(cat template.json)

if [ -e $WORKSPACE/project-CRMGP/historique.json ];
then
  jq '. + [input]' historique.json template.json > historique1.json 
else
  cat <<-EOF > historique.json
   [
    $a
   ]
EOF
fi

mv historique1.json historique.json
```

Answer (score 0):

> This my script script.sh

Please use a decicated tool to process JSON. With [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) for instance you don't even need the *'script.sh'* at all:

```
$ xidel -s template.json -e '
  if (file:exists("'$WORKSPACE/project-CRMGP/historique.json'")) then
    array{
      json-doc("'$WORKSPACE/project-CRMGP/historique.json'")(),
      $json
    }
  else
    array{$json}
'
[
  {
    "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
    "PTF_CONTENT": [
      {
        "NAME": "api_batch_API",
        "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
        "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "PTF_INSTALL_DATE": " 2020-03-31 09:12:10",
    "PTF_CONTENT": [
      {
        "NAME": "api_batch_API",
        "CHECKED": "api_batch_NOT_SELECTED",
        "VERSION": "G02R00C13_c14"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```